# How to get table cell value on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a simple table with 5 columns. Last column is the button. I need to get the first column cell value on button click and take this value to action/controller. I want to achieve this without using javascript.

So is there any ready made way of doing this in asp.net mvc 4 as i did many times in asp.net webforms easily, Here is my code following:-

```
        @if (Model != null)
        {

            foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
            {   

            <tr style="height: 22px; border-bottom: 1px solid gray">
                <td>@row["instr_no"]</td>
                <td>@row["benef_name"]</td>
                <td>@row["instr_date"]</td>
                <td>@row["maker_id"]</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Print", "Print", "Home", new { instr_no = "FirstCellValue" }) </td>

            </tr>
            }
        }

    </tbody>
```

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Print", "Print", "Home", new { instr_no = row["instr_no"] }, null)`

Comment: @Shyju, Thanks for the reply, Please see comments of Mr. Stephen Muecke. It is is working fine and your code is working too. Then what is the main difference between your and Stephen Muecke method? If we can achieve the thing without using (Html.BeginForm("Print","Home")). then what is the need of it, thanks. –

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` generates an `<a>` element and makes a GET to you method. The code in Shyju's answer is using a form and making a POST (which you would use it you were updating data). Based on your link being "Print", I assume your not changing data so you should use `ActionLink()`

Comment: Nice and simple explanation, How can i mark your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the value of the property as route value in the link using

```
@Html.ActionLink("Print", "Print", "Home", new { instr_no = row["instr_no"] }, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use javascript, you can do a form submit.

Wrap each of your row inside a form tag. Set the first cell's value to a hidden input field. When user clicks on the submit button, It will submit that value.

```
<table>    
    @foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Print","Home"))
        {
            <tr style="height: 22px; border-bottom: 1px solid gray">   

                <td>@row["instr_no"] <input type="hidden" value="@row["instr_no"]" 
                                                                  name="instrNo" /></td>    
                <td>@row["benef_name"]</td>
                <td><input type="submit" /></td>

            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Assuming you have an action method called `Print` in your HomeController which accepts a parameter with name `instrNo`

```
public ActionResult Print(string instrNo)
{
  // to do : Return something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Please see comments of Mr.  Stephen Muecke. It is is working fine and your code is  working too. Then what is the main difference between your and Stephen Muecke method? If we can achieve the thing without using (Html.BeginForm("Print","Home")). then what is the need of it, thanks.

Comment: Yes. If you want to open it in a new link with the instr_no in querystring, That would work perfectly fine. If you do not want to show the instr_no in querystring of the url of the page, you can use form posting. The value will be posted as the request body.  It is useful if you want to stay in the same page but want to download an image when you click post.